# Most Efficient way of handling Images In ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am making an image view app, I have images in an arrayList(for testing purposes), when user clicks on an image in GridView its passed to another activity to be viewed in full screen, I thought of adding gestures such as swipe left and right, how but the problem is its in another activity, I cannot directly access the Images because they are in another activity so I cannot swipe unless I pass the image arrayList with the image to be opened every time to the other activity which seems to be not so efficient, how can I go around this?

Code that is Passing the image and image ArrayList to activity 2 so that image can be Opened in FullScreen:

```
   gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            intent.putExtra("imagesReference", getData());
```

Code that is getting the sent data in activity 2 and displaying data:

```
 String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image");
    images = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("imagesReference");
    imagePosition = getIntent().getStringExtra("position");
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    titleTextView.setText(title);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: you can make public static your arrayList to give access to another class

Comment: Why do you say that wouldn't be efficient? If you add a code snippet, it will help people understand your question better.

Comment: @bernie i have posted a snippet of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i follow your question than you can pass image from one activity to another.
Convert ImageView to Bitmap

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

In second Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

**Solution 2:** (for drawable easy & light way)

Send the resource integer value like:

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("resourseInt", R.drawable.image);    
startActivity(intent);
```

SECOND ACTIVITY

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) 
{ 

    super.onCreate(bundle); 
    setContentView(R.layout.pantalla); 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (extras == null) 
    { 
        return; 
    } 
    int res = extras.getInt("resourseInt"); 

    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.something); 

    view.setImageResourse(res); 
}

     Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Then display bitmap in ImageView.

Comment: pleasure to help. happy coding :)